# rails 'form_tag' defaults to POST method but submits with GET method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, httprequest

I have this form:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: :orders, action: :create_user) do %>

  <%= label_tag 'first_name', 'First Name' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'first_name' %><br/>

  <%= label_tag 'last_name', 'Last Name' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'last_name' %><br/>

  <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
  <%= email_field_tag 'email' %> <br />

  <%= label_tag 'username', 'Username' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'username' %> <br/>

  <%= label_tag 'password', 'Password' %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'password' %><br />

  <%= label_tag 'password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password' %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'password_confirmation' %><br />

  <%= submit_tag 'Create' %>

<% end %>
```

The `create_user` action in `orders` controller looks like this:

```
def create_user
  hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra

  post_user = Typhoeus::Request.new(
    "localhost:3006/api/v1/users.json",
    method: :post,
    headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    body: params.except(:authenticity_token).to_json
  )

  post_user.on_complete do |response|
    if response.success?
      user = User.from_json(response.body)
      @user = user.user

      respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to controller: :orders, action: :account_created, user_id: @user.id}
      end

    elsif response.timed_out?
      logger.debug "got a time out"

    elsif response.code == 0
      logger.debug(response.return_message)

    else
      # Received a non-successful http response.
      logger.debug("HTTP request failed: " + response.code.to_s)
    end
  end
  hydra.queue post_user
  hydra.run
end
```

I have this in `config/routes.rb`

```
post '/orders/users/create_user', to: 'orders#create_user'
```

when i submit the form, I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/orders/users/create_user"
```

I am wondering why the application is using `GET` to submit the form or where this `GET` request is coming from. when I inspect the form source using the browser, the form mark up looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders/users/create_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="toYBO4DzVYK30M4uiBRtxCIZ2OSR/g1kMe4qrTzrmQM=" /></div>

  <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
  <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" /><br/>

  <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
  <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" /><br/>

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" /> <br />

  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" name="username" type="text" /> <br/>

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" /><br />

  <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
  <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" type="password" /><br />

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create" />

</form>
```

where is this `GET` request coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use route and its http request, try this

```
<%= form_tag( '/orders/users/create_user', :method => :post ) do %>
```

Routes.rb

```
post "/orders/users/create_user" => "orders#create_user", :as => :create_user
```

or

```
match "/orders/users/create_user" => "orders#create_user", :via => :post, :as => :create_user
```

Comment: I do not want the form to submit with a `get` request. I want a `post`